# How do I parse RSS-CB data using C#?

Tags: c#, rss

Has anyone experience getting values from a RSS-CB file, I would like to get the value from:

```
<cb:value frequency="daily" decimals="4">1.3607</cb:value>.
```

The location of the rss is http://www.ecb.int/rss/fxref-usd.html. Any tips what the best way is to go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.rssdotnet.com/. It is very good at reading RSS feeds. And Im pretty sure you will be able to add a namespace to the parser so you can get to the value you want

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq to XML along with the XNamespace class. More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387069.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck using the 2.0 framework in this existing project, it did cross my mind. Thanks!